# Function LookAt to turn around an object ?

Tags: three.js

as part of a project, I have to turn the camera around an object (position 0, 0,0) which remains to him still. For this, I want to know if the LookAt function is the one that is best suited , And also how does it work?

Comment: Did you have a look at `OrbitControls`?  https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit

Comment: Yes I saw it, but I do not know how to use it, rather I do not know how to modify it for what I want to do, because what I want is that in the center there is a sphere Or other and that one can turn around with the camera, be using keys or with the mouse.

Comment: One small gotcha with LookAt(). When you call camera.LookAt( mesh ), `mesh` must be a Vector3! So you should call it like so: `camera.LookAt( mesh.position );`

Answer (score 0):

Integrating `OrbitControls` should be done with a few lines of code. So, the basic lines of code should be:

```js
// init
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enableZoom = false; // optional
controls.enablePan = false; // optional
controls.center.set(0,0,0); // should be initially 0,0,0
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // if you are not using requestAnimationFrame()

camera.position.z = 500; // should be bigger than the radius of your sphere

// render
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Now, you should be able to rotate the camera around your sphere using your mouse.

All the other essential stuff (camera, renderer) can be found at the example: https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit

Comment: Thank you ,but there is a problem :"Cannot read property 'domElement' of undefined " :'(

Comment: Of course you need to instantiate the renderer (`renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();`), camera, and scene like in every three.js project and like in the example. I just showed the essential lines of code regarding the OrbitControls.

Comment: Is it possible that I show you my program to tell me what should be changed please (if yes ,I don't know how to send it :'(  )

Comment: You can edit your question an paste your code there, you can set up a jsfiddle and copy the link here (or in your question), or you can just copy a link from where I can download your code.

Comment: I would first like to thank you for the help you bring me :)

Comment: I only added `var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );` (and added three.js and OrbitControls.js to the resources to make work) https://jsfiddle.net/mfajjp1u/1/

Comment: Can you help me one more time please?

Comment: I have to put square into a div /the square must stay into the leftbox :https://jsfiddle.net/soty92L5/      What do I have to change please ?

Comment: I guess, you want to put the 3D content into the `Géométrie` div. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/soty92L5/1/ Please accept the answer above, if it helped you.

Comment: Sorry to answer you so late. After adding your program to mine there are 2 problems: first with the "$" symbole or when I remove it : there is an error: "TypeError: container.width is not a function".

Comment: `$` is the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) namespace. On jsfiddle, you can see that I added jQuery as external resource. Download `jquery.js` or `jquery.min.js` and add it in your html file (`<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`).

Comment: thank you for your help. can help one more time please: what do I have to change to modify the height width and depth please. what do I have to modify to replace th cube by a sphere for example

Comment: You could either scale the box (e.g. `box.scale.set(2, 2.5, 1);`), or replace the geometry of the box by a new one (`box.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 125, 50);`). To replace the cube by a sphere, you need to remove the box from scene and add the sphere: `scene.remove(box); scene.add(sphere);`

Comment: Can you help me to add differents plane on x,y,z please :https://jsfiddle.net/74j2m86t/1/

Comment: I don't know why `onclick` is not working. I added an id tag to the button and bound the click event to the function with jQuery. `$('#planx').on('click', planx);` https://jsfiddle.net/74j2m86t/2/